# How to avoid this splitting of single line as multi lines in SplitText?

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have CSV file which contains following line.

```
No,NAme,ID,Description
1,Stack,232,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
 -- Jiuaslkm asdasdasd"
```

used below processor structure GetFile-->SplitText

In SplitText i have given header and line split count as 1.

So i think it could be split row as below..,

```
 No,NAme,ID,Description
1,Stack,232,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
 -- Jiuaslkm asdasdasd:"
```

But it actually split the csv as "2" splits like below.,

**First SPlit:**

```
No,NAme,ID,Description
1,Stack,232,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
```

**Second Split:**

```
No,NAme,ID,Description
    -- Jiuaslkm asdasdasd"
```

So i have faced data handling missed something.

*GOal:Now i need to handle those data lines as single line.*

```
EDIT 1:
```

After replace Text.,

it could be replace \n by below.,

```
No,NAme,ID,Description
\n1,Stack,232,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
 \n-- Jiuaslkm asdasdasd"
```

It could n't convert as single split but it yield result same like above only.

**EDIT 2:**

My ReplaceTextProcessor having following values.

```
Search Value:"(.*?)(\n)(.*?)"

Replacement Value:"$1\\n$3"

Character Set:UTF-8

MaximumBuffer Size:1MB

Replacement Strategy:Regex Replace

Evaluation Mode:Entire Text
```

Let me know if anything am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is clearly a newline character of some kind in the "row" you have provided.

```
No,NAme,ID,Description          (1)
1,Stack,232,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO    (2)
 -- Jiuaslkm asdasdasd"         (3)
```

If you want newlines inside paired `"` to be ignored, you'll have to escape them somehow (i.e. `ReplaceText` before `SplitText` with a token and then reverse the operation after splitting). Try using the regex `"(.*?)(\n)(.*?)"` replaced with `"$1\\n$3"`. That will handle the case you have above.

```
No,NAme,ID,Description
1,Stack,232,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
 -- Jiuaslkm asdasdasd"
2,Queue,454,"PQRSTUVWXYZ
 -- Other words here"
```

becomes

```
No,NAme,ID,Description
1,Stack,232,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO\n -- Jiuaslkm asdasdasd"
2,Queue,454,"PQRSTUVWXYZ\n -- Other words here"
```

and then after the split

```
No,NAme,ID,Description
1,Stack,232,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO\n -- Jiuaslkm asdasdasd"
```

and

```
No,NAme,ID,Description
2,Queue,454,"PQRSTUVWXYZ\n -- Other words here"
```

If you need to handle arbitrary numbers of `\n`, you'll need to use something more complex (I don't think look-aheads can handle this natively, you'll need to loop `ReplaceText` to itself or you might need `ExecuteScript`).

**Update**

There was a regression bug introduced in the latest release which breaks this flow. It is a known issue [NIFI-3255](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3255) and the Jira captures the `IllegalArgumentException` being thrown by `SplitText`. If you run with the patch applied, this flow works perfectly. I've provided a [template](https://gist.github.com/alopresto/09b30565c9c2632658bc2423a6b3a752) and [log output](https://gist.github.com/alopresto/461cd12b64336ffc65cab093c0a491fc).

Comment: can you check my edited query? if i use replace text inbetween getfile and split text leads same issue i have faced

Comment: The double quotes `"` are necessary *in* the regex to tell it to only replace *actual newlines* with the `\n` character when it is detected inside a pair of `"`. You have to provide them in the search regex for it to work.

Comment: i have used GetFile,ReplaceText,SplitText.In replace text search value is "(.*?)(\n)(.*?)" and replacement vlaue is "$1\\n$3".It have n't replaced correctly

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the configuration of the `ReplaceText` processor.

Comment: i have edited my question which have my ReplaceText attributes.

Comment: while see JIRA it shows affect versions NiFi 1.0 and 1.1 .But i have using NiFi-0.6.1

Comment: 0.6.1 is an unsupported version. I would recommend you upgrade to 0.7.x or (preferably) 1.1.x.